# Decoding sampled bitmap returns null if too large

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, decode

I am trying to decode an image taken on an android device without running out of memory on the device, i finally came across [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) guide and followed it resulting in these 3 methods:

```
public static FileDescriptor getDescriptorFromFile(File file, Context context) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(photoUri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();

    return fd;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(FileDescriptor descriptor, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(descriptor, null, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(descriptor, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

These methods are used like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_taken);
int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();

final FileDescriptor fd = CameraUtils.getDescriptorFromFile(filePath, this);
Bitmap bitmap = CameraUtils.decodeSampledBitmap(fd, 250, 250);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Ideally i want those 250 values to be set to the width and height of the view, but when i make them any bigger decodeSampleBitmap() returns null and i cannot for the life of me work out why?

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated thanks.

**EDIT:**

Now that i've made my capture image a little larger i again had to make these values even smaller so that it doesn't return null. The values now cannot be larger than 150, 150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have managed to fix this by simply switching from

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(descriptor, null, options);
```

to:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, options);
```

I don't know why this makes such a big difference but it definitely does, the quality of the image output is perfect, virtually no quality lost, no memory issues.

My full code looks like this:

Decoding:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(File file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
}
```

Calculating sample size:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Use:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_taken);
int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();

File file = //get your file
Bitmap bitmap = CameraUtils.decodeSampledBitmap(file, height, width);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Note: i use height as width and vice versa because i later rotate the bitmap 90 degrees.